# Can I just implement RoleProvider without MembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider

I am developing an intranet application with Windows Authentication, I have implemented a custom role provider and tied that in with my repository which has Users and Roles.

I use `[Authorize(Role="Administrator")]` on my controller class. I am logged in as "UserA", and I have implemented `GetRolesForUser(string username)`. Additionally, "UserA" is an "Administrator" role however Authorization still seems to fail.

Do I still have to implement the MembershipProvider?

Comment: You use __Windows Authentication__ _and_ you have Users in your repository?

Comment: What membership provider do you use for now? Do you have any registered in web.config?

Comment: @henk How else do I associate users into roles for the RoleProvider implementation?

Comment: Usually with Forms authentication.

Comment: Ok the problem was that I didn't have Windows Authentication set to on in the web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication does not require a MembershipProvider. You can use any RoleProvider you want.

One thing to check in your role provider is how the username is stored. The Windows Authentication identity is DOMAIN\UserName. Make sure your role provider stores usernames in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can implement Role-provider without Membeship Provider definitely...

If you're looking to write a role provider, use the existing role provider code for a starting point or learning exercise. Get it from..

[Role ProviderToolKitSamples](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi.)